# How to use StringField to validate phone number in Flask form ? Defining min/max length can't restrict user from entering text

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms

I am coding a python flask app and I defined a Contact field using the string field type.

I would like to validate the field to accept numbers only mobile numbers. Please guide!

```py
contact = StringField('Contact',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=10, max=10)])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Regular Expressions validator `Regexp()` like this:

```
contact = StringField('Contact',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=10, max=10),Regexp(regex='^[+-]?[0-9]$')])
```

`^`  means start of string.

`$` end of string.

`[-+]?`means an optional `+` or `-` ( ? means optional) and [ ] is for a set of characters.

`[0-9]+` the `+` means one or more digits.

You can find more about wtforms' Regexp() class from [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/validators/#Regexp).

Comment: like:  contact = StringField('Contact',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=10, max=14),Regexp(regex='^[+-]?[0-9]+$')])